# Backtrack install in vm workstation

Tags: partitioning, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, disc

I am trying to install **Linux Backtrack 5 R3** using VM Workstation on my Microsoft Windows Vista PC.
 I have installed BT5 on dual boot using a live cd on a laptop before but i am encountering this issue with the VM Workstation after `startx` then proceeding to step 4 of 7 which is to prepare disc space there is no slider to patroon space it also says this computer has no operating system on it how can this be as it had Windows Vista or is this meaning in the VM Workstation? 
 I am also presented with two options, them being:

1. Erase and use entire disc - would  this wipe Windows Vista off my hard drive ?
2. Specify disc manually

It seems i should choose option two then press forward. If I need to install using this option how would I proceed step by step?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a Virtual Disk for your virtual machine in Vmware then you will be ok - BT5 will install on the virtual disk.

Comment: thanks for your answer are you saying that the virtual disc is in the vm workstation and that my windows vista will be untouched ?can anyone say this is correct for certain ? Thanks

Comment: It is impossible for you to over-write vista with anything you do.